# jQuery trigger keyup on input gets old value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to manually trigger key-up event in qunit test but it fails since manually trigger key-up event will not change the input value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Re9bj/4/

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (event) {
    $('div').html($('input').val());
});

var e = $.Event('keyup', {
    keycode: 68
});
$('input').trigger(e); //this trigger will not change the input value
```

This trigger will work but the problem is that input value never change.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please be clear.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha , what I want to achieve a test of this feature: when user typing in an input, a link of a button is update. I successfully implement this feature but failed to test it, since trigger keyup event does not have default behaviour as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a character with a simple trigger. Trigger will only fire events, but not the default behavior. You need to simulate it.

To do that, you can use this code :

```
if(event.isTrigger && event.keycode) this.value +=  String.fromCharCode(event.keycode);
```

It will check if the event is triggered and then print the value.

Final code :

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (event) {
    if(event.isTrigger && event.keycode) this.value +=  String.fromCharCode(event.keycode);
    $('div').html($('input').val());
});

var e = $.Event('keyup', {
    keycode: 68
});
$('input').trigger(e);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Re9bj/9/